# Function of two variables representation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A function of one variable is presented as [image]

what would be an equivalent presentation for  functions of two variables *f(x,y)* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like this:

$\phantom{X}\;\;$[image: made by your humble correspondent Hakim ;-)]

Comment: Assuming $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Nameless Not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the domain. Based on that you could simply go with ordered pairs, or perhaps you could have an array to represent your domain. The range could then be represented the same way with arrows between the two as before.

Note that the above only deals with he discrete case, similar to what you have presented. For continuous cases, really you'd just have a 2D region of space as your domain to map to some subset of the real line (presumably)

Answer (score 1):

Actually this doesn't imply how many variables there are. It looks like it's a function of one *integer* argument, but the set on the left may contain any domain. Function of many variables is just a function of ordered tuples (pairs, triplets,...). So just write the set on the left as $\{ (1,1), (0,1), (1.5,3), (\pi,-\pi),\ldots\}$ and you have a function of two variables. The concept of dimensionality only follows when you introduce continuity of the domain and select a metric. The function itself doesn't care about the structure of the domain space. They don't even have to be numbers. A function can map from any the space of functions, symbols, words, you name it.

For instance, if you have a function of two integers, $f(x,y)$ you can also write the exactly same function as a function of one integer $f(z)$ where $z$ is constructed from alternating digits of $x$ and $y$ (for instance, x=1242, y=54, $z=\color{red}{1}0\color{red}{2}5\color{red}{4}4\color{red}{2}$). The diagram is the same, the function does the same thing and the domain contains the same elements, they are just relabeled from ordered pairs (x,y) to a single integer z.

If the domain is continuous (let's say $\mathbb{R}^2$), you can't do that, because there is no continuous mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but if continuity is not required, you can still do it. It's just a matter of representation.